# Include Vidalia/Tor into another Program

Tags: c#, proxy, include, tor

I want to make a small webbrowser for anonymous and secure webbrowsing and I want to use Vidalia/Tor for the anonymity, it shall use the Tor proxy 127.0.0.1:8118 by standart.
Now I want to make this simple so a user doesn't have to run vidalia when he wants to use this webbrowser.
Is there a way to make vidalia automatically run in the background when someone starts my browser?
I'm running on Windows 7 64 bit and use VS2012

Comment: Need more info. What OS are you running on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use Vidalia, because it's purpose is just to control/monitor tor.  You can have your program perform this function instead.  You want to get the "expert bundle", which is just tor itself with no supporting programs.  The tor license allows you to redistribute it with your program.

Put some code in your browser that checks for port 8118 being open.  If it's not, it should try to launch tor, then wait for port 8118 to open.  You probably also want it to kill the tor process when it exits.

Comment: Is it possible to open multiple tors to have different ips for different tabs?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to launch it multiple times with different port numbers.  See this question for details:  http://serverfault.com/questions/136072/how-to-run-multiple-instances-of-tor

Comment: Is it also possible to "emulate" what tor does and directly include that into the program or is that too much of work?

Comment: It's open source, so you could get the source code and incorporate it directly in your program, but it's probably written in C, and your program is written in C#, so you'd have to port it.  Not fun.